# Inserting a new key if a particular key value matches in both the arrays

Tags: php

```
$array1 = array(
                 [0] => array(
                          'id' => 'gdye6378399sjwui39',
                          'name' => 'Plate 1'
                        ),
                 [1] => array(
                          'id' => 'xyz6378399sjwui39',
                          'name' => 'Plate 2'
                        ),
                 [2] => array(
                          'id' => 'tr2e6378399sjwui39',
                          'name' => 'Plate 3'
                        )
             )
```

and another array

```
$array2 =  array(
                 [0] => array(
                          'id' => 'gdye6378399sjwui39',
                          'ETA' => '8'
                        ),
                 [1] => array(
                          'id' => 'tr2e6378399sjwui39',
                          'ETA' => '9'
                        )
                 [2] => array(
                          'id' => 'xyz6378399sjwui39',
                          'ETA' => '5'
                        )

             )
```

I want to compare the two arrays. I am doing it like this way:-

```
if(!empty($array2))
{
   foreach($array1 as $ck => $cl)
   {
       foreach($array12 as $ued){
       if($cl['id'] == $ued['id'])
       {
          $array1[$ck]['ETA'] = $ued['ETA'];
          break;
       }
    }
}
```

What are the other better ways to do this? The order of the two arrays may vary, and so does the size.

Comment: Please try in_array() function.

Comment: Your examples don't seem to match with your problem, or the examples are unclear/erratic. Can you provide a [*minimal*, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @RomeoSierra, Updated the doc

Answer (score 0):

If you index the second array by the id (using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)) you can get away without using the inner `foreach()` and just use `isset()`...

```
$match = array_column($array2, null, 'id');
foreach ( $array1 as $ck=>$cl)   {
    if ( isset($match[$cl['id']]) )    {
        $array1[$ck]['ETA'] = $match[$cl['id']]['ETA'];
    }
}

print_r($array1);
```